# JSTL LocalDateTime format

Tags: jsp, jstl, date-format, java-time

I want to format my Java 8 `LocalDateTime` object in **"dd.MM.yyyy**" pattern. Is there any library to format? I tried code below but got conversion exception.

```
<fmt:parseDate value="${date}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" var="parsedDate" type="date" />
```

Is there any tag or converter for `LocalDateTime` class in JSTL?

Comment: See also: https://github.com/sargue/java-time-jsptags

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Actually I had the same problem and ended up forking the original Joda Time jsp tags to create [Java 8 java.time JSP tags](https://github.com/sargue/java-time-jsptags).

With that library your example would be something like this:

```
<javatime:parseLocalDateTime value="${date}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" var="parsedDate" />
```

Check the repository for installation instructions: https://github.com/sargue/java-time-jsptags

Comment: I have tried, this is successful and it has easy shortcut for parsing and formating.

Answer (score 28):

It doesn't exist in the 14-year old JSTL.

Your best bet is creating a custom EL function. First create an utility method.

```
package com.example;

public final class Dates {
     private Dates() {}

     public static String formatLocalDateTime(LocalDateTime localDateTime, String pattern) {
         return localDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern));
     }
}
```

Then create a `/WEB-INF/functions.tld` wherein you register the utility method as an EL function:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<taglib 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">

    <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
    <short-name>Custom_Functions</short-name>
    <uri>http://example.com/functions</uri>

    <function>
        <name>formatLocalDateTime</name>
        <function-class>com.example.Dates</function-class>
        <function-signature>java.lang.String formatLocalDateTime(java.time.LocalDateTime, java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    </function>
</taglib>
```

Finally use it as below:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://example.com/functions" prefix="f" %>

<p>Date is: ${f:formatLocalDateTime(date, 'dd.MM.yyyy')}</p>
```

Extend if necessary the method to take a `Locale` argument.

Answer (score 11):

No, It does not exist for LocalDateTime.

However, you can use:

```
<fmt:parseDate value="${ cleanedDateTime }" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm" var="parsedDateTime" type="both" />
<fmt:formatDate pattern="dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm" value="${ parsedDateTime }" />
```

Comment: nice this works great with jstl sql datetime

Answer (score 5):

Here is my solution (I'm using Spring MVC).

In the controller add a SimpleDateFormat with the LocalDateTime pattern as a model attribute:

```
model.addAttribute("localDateTimeFormat", new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm"));
```

Then use it in the JSP to parse the LocalDateTime and get a java.util.Date:

```
${localDateTimeFormat.parse(date)}
```

Now you can parse it with JSTL.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest using `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`.
First import it to JSP `<%@ page import="java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter" %>`, then format variable `${localDateTime.format( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy"))}`.
Being new to java development, I'm interested wether this approach is acceptable in terms of 'best practice'.