# Using Java8 time in JSPs

Tags: jsp, struts2, el, java-time, valuestack

For my open source project I'm in the process of switching date fields from `java.util.Date` to Java 8's `java.time.LocalDateTime`.

In the JSP's I'm using Struts tags to format the `java.util.Date` from the passed-in bean, however, those won't work with Java 8 time.  I use the Struts tag not only to retrieve the time field but also the formatting string to be used to parse it:

```jsp
<s:text name="generic.date.toStringFormat">
    <s:param value="myBean.timeField" />
</s:text>
```

`"generic.date.toStringFormat"` is in the message resource file, and myBean.timeField is from the Action form backing the JSP.

Looking at this post: [JSTL LocalDateTime format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35606551/jstl-localdatetime-format), it seems there are two alternatives I can use, Sargue's https://github.com/sargue/java-time-jsptags or a custom EL function, for example with the former:

```jsp
<javatime:format value="myBean.timeField" pattern="generic.date.toStringFormat"/>
```

Problem is, `"myBean.timeField"` and `"generic.date.toStringFormat"` seem to be resolvable only within Struts tags.  If `<javatime>` were a standard HTML tag, I could use `<s:property/>` to get the values resolved, e.g.,

```jsp
<span><s:property value="myBean.timeField"/></span>
```

But `<javatime:.../>` is a JSP tag and I can't seem to resolve Struts JSP tags within other JSP tags.  Question:  How can I extract the bean value `myBean.timeField` and the message resource value `generic.date.toStringFormat` into variables so I can reference them in the `<javatime/>` tag above?  (If this can be done via the custom EL function option instead, that will work for me also.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use EL in the `value` attribute. Struts2 wrapped a request to search attributes from the `valueStack`. This is native access to your action variables from the EL.

```
<javatime:parseLocalDateTime value="${myBean.timeField}" pattern="generic.date.toStringFormat" var="parsedDate" />
```

Comment: ${myBean.timeField} works perfectly, thx, the pattern portion (with or without the ${ }'s) is still failing though, I'm going to see if I can use the JSTL fmt tag to extract the resource value into a var so I can do something like pattern={$patternVar} in the jt:pLDT tag.

Answer (score 1):

More information to add to Roman's answer:  To obtain the pattern from a resource file, add in the JSTL fmt tag and place it into a variable:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<fmt:message key="generic.date.toStringFormat" var="dateFormat"/>
```

Taken together with Roman's solution above for extracting `${myBean.timeField}`:

```
<javatime:format value="${myBean.timeField}" pattern="${dateFormat}" />
```

As an aside, for date variables being retrieved from a Struts iterator tag:

```
<s:date name="#iter.myDateField"/>
```

This can be replaced by using the Struts set tag:

```
<s:set var="tempTime" value="#comment.postTime"/>
<javatime:format value="${tempTime}" pattern="${dateFormat}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it has been fixed in **Struts 6.2**.

Sources :

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-5295
- https://github.com/apache/struts/commit/34208e69609567143901678936f34bad3cb11ab2